# How to find the center point which lies on the LineString geometry?

Tags: postgis

I have a `LineString` geometry which is `U shaped` like and I'd like to find the center point of the geometry which lies on the LineString. I've already used **`st_centroid`** but the returned geometry isn't on the LineString.

I would like to know which function should be used in PostGIS to achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: It would also help to show what you mean by "actual center". Perhaps read http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/geometry_returning.html

Comment: @underdark Thanks for the response. I edited the question.

Comment: @BradHards I'll read the article, that's what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The documentation for [`st_centroid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html), [`st_pointOnSurface`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_PointOnSurface.html) and [`st_line_interpolate_point`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html) have neat images describing them.

`st_centroid` gives you the geometric centroid point, which can be outside of the source geometry (think of a line shaped as a U, the centroid will not be on the line).

`st_pointOnSurface` returns a point that is for sure on the surface (on the line, inside a polygon), but you don't know where it is. It is very useful for label placement.

`st_line_interpolate_point`, used with a parameter of .5 (50%) will return the point, on the input line, located in the middle.

Comment: Answer was relevant to original question... Not so much for the completly changed one